# Prevent datetime field conversion in Fractal Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using [dingo](https://github.com/dingo/api) laravel package to create an API. As you know it uses another package named [Fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/) to output restful data structures.

But a problem that I have with them is automatically convert DateTime formatted fields like `created_at` and `updated_at` to an object includes `date` , `timezone_type` and `timezone` property.

Now I want to prevent this conversion. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an answer [here](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/859#issuecomment-188399174).

This is because the Carbon object when casted to JSON returns that representation.

You have multiple ways of solving this:

```
(string) $model->created_at, // or
$model->created_at->toDateTimeString(), // or
$model->created_at->getTimestamp() // to show a UNIX timestamp
```

Comment: Keep in mind, if you use **toDateTimeString** or **getTimestamp** approach you have to make additional checks to prevent `Call to a member function toDateTimeString() on null` errors. For example, if you use SoftDeletes `deleted_at` is likely to be null very often. As for me, these checks make transformers too dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Another (and cleaner as for me) method is a [Global Customization Via Carbon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#date-serialization):

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($carbon) {
        return $carbon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    });
}
```

Now in your transformers, you can just use:

```
'created_at' => $post->created_at,
'updated_at' => $post->updated_at,
'deleted_at' => $post->deleted_at,
```

without the need of checking whether a `$post->deleted_at` is `null`.

Comment: Since the `serializeUsing()` static setter is deprecated in Carbon the best solution I've found so far is `'deleted_at' => optional($audio->deleted_at)->toDateTimeString(),`